# Get Date only from SubmitDate

Tags: javascript, node.js

This logic attempt to get Date only from `SubmitDate`

For example:

2011-03-22 17:25:13 would return 2011-03-22

If `SubmitDate` property does not exist or could not `.split`, then it should return null.

```
function getDateOnly(record) {
  if (typeof record.SubmitDate !== "undefined") {
    return (record.SubmitDate.split(" ")[0])? record.SubmitDate.split(" ")[0] : null;
  }

  return null;
}
```

For example

```
console.log(getDate({ SubmitDate: "2011-03-22 17:25:13" }));
```

would return 2011-03-22

I am having problem when trying:

```
console.log(getDate({ SubmitDate: null }));
```

This would throw an error:

> Cannot read property 'split' of null

How would you fix this or refactor the logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `&&`

```
  return record.SubmitDate && record.SubmitDate.split(" ")[0]
           ? record.SubmitDate.split(" ")[0] 
           : null;
```

If `record.SubmitDate` evaluates as a false then the next part after `&&`, which is `record.SubmitDate.split(" ")[0]`, will not be checked and evaluated =)

Comment: What case that `record.SubmitDate` return false?

Comment: Why no need for  `typeof record.SubmitDate !== "undefined"` ?

Comment: There is problem if you try: `console.log(getDate({ SubmitDate: 12 }));`  12 is integer which should return null

Comment: `undefined` is evaluated as a `false` in conditional statement.

Comment: `console.log(getDate({ SubmitDate: 12 }));` well this is a different case for validating the input

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back simple check with regex for at least format might look like
`/^\d{1,4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}/.test(date)`